# Best practices to be followed for Tablespace creation in oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespace

In my current application all tables are mapped to USERS table-space. I don't have much idea on how to organize table-space efficiently. This is what I'm thinking:

a. Based on row_counts, I'm planning to have three table-space. Small, Medium and Large.

b. Have different table-space for indexes itself.

Is this good enough or any other suggestion? BTW, I'm using Oracle 12c database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry about splitting data over different tablespaces for data or indexes - thats very out dated thinking. The one thing that you *may* want to consider is if you are implementing some sort of data lief cycle, where by you need to archive off data (files). In that case, I might implement some sort of tablespaces strategy to support that. For example, may have a tablespace for each year of data, as I will only hold a rolling 7 years of data. Older data gets archived to offline storage.